# How to add a SELECT statement result?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a DB with which I am running the below command. The aim is to show the HOURS field from each ROW where the DATE is equal to 02/08/2013. What I then want to do it to add the results and display as a total amount.

```
SELECT HOURS FROM RESOURCE WHERE DATE = '02/08/2013';
```

Current the results is 20 40 18. What I want is to output the total 78.

I have tried the below, but that just counts the results, 3.

```
SELECT COUNT(HOURS) FROM RESOURCE WHERE DATE = '02/08/2013'
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think I may have just figured it out. SELECT SUM(HOURS) FROM RESOURCE WHERE DATE = '02/08/2013'

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thats the one. Post as an answer and I will accept. Cheers for your quick response.

Comment: @Orangecrush- Thats why i gave an up vote to your answer. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
SELECT SUM(HOURS) FROM RESOURCE WHERE DATE = '02/08/2013';
```

**[SQL FIDDLE OUTPUT](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ffeb/3/0)**